# Using third party component in Liferay

Tags: jquery, liferay

I am new to Liferay. How can I use the third party components (jquery datepicker) in the liferay? Any step by step explanation from referring the scripts and intializing the component will be much helpful. Thanks in advance

Comment: Quick question - what Liferay version are you on? The Liferay taglibs already provide these type of date pickers.

Answer (score 0):

What I have done and still works is:

In my jsp, after html, you must add 3 parts of javascript code:

1 -

```
<script>
    define._amd = define.amd;
    define.amd = false;
</script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
```

2 - Your js code, this is just an example:

```
<script> 
    (function($) {
        $(function() {
            var $j = jQuery.noConflict();
            var a = "${myDate}";
            var splitted = a.split("-");
            var newFechaStr = splitted[2]+ "/" + splitted[1] + "/" + splitted[0];
            $j("#datepickerIda").datetimepicker({
                timepicker:false,
                format:'d/m/Y',
                value:newFechaStr,
                dayOfWeekStart:1
        });
    $j.datetimepicker.setLocale('es');

   });
})(jQuery);
</script>
```

3 -

```
<script>
   define.amd = define._amd;
</script>
```